# Trying to create a zero matrix of size m*n using lists but I'm unable to print the output in desired shape

Tags: python, list, matrix

```
M=[]
for j in range(3):
   l=[]
   for k in range(3):
       l.append(0)
   M.append(l)
print(M)
```

OUTPUT:[[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0]]

But I want the output to be printed like this:
[[0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0]]

Comment: What are you passing in for `m` and `n`?

Comment: I'm referring to specific numbers that you're using to reproduce the issue.

Comment: m = 3 and n = 3      .

Comment: Use `m = 3` and `n = 4`?

Comment: sorry I edited to make sure I'm asking correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to print the output in the shape that you want you can do

```
for item in M:
    if item is M[-1]:
        print(f"{item}]")
    elif item is M[0]:
        print(f"[{item},")
    else:
        print(f"{item},")
```

instead of just printing M